# Showing space is complete and functional is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I've got two questions.

(1) Define $
\|f\| := |f(0)| +  \max \limits_{0 \le t \le 1} |f'(t)|$ to be a norm on $C^1([0,1])$.
(I have shown it's indeed a norm).

Show that $(C^1([0,1]), \|\cdot\|)$ is complete. Here's my work:

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $(f_n)$ be cauchy in $(C([0,1]), \|\cdot\|)$. Then, for all $m,n$ greater than some $N$, we have
$$
\|f_n - f_m\|<\epsilon \implies |f_n(0)-f_m(0)|<\epsilon \text{  and also  } \| f_n' - f_m'\|_\infty < \epsilon.
$$
By completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ and $(C([0,1]), \|\cdot\|_\infty)$, respectively, we get $f_n(0) \to a_0$ and $f_n' \to g$.

Now, we want to show $f_n \to a_0 + \int g$ or something, but I'm stuck. I'm guessing there's some ODE theory that I don't know.

(2) Let $P([0,1])$ be the set of all polynomials on $[0,1]$ with the same norm as above. Is $\phi(f) = f''(1/2)$ a bounded linear functional?

I have shown that the operators $f \mapsto f(1/2)$ and $f \mapsto f'(1/2)$ are bounded linear functionals. But I can't do it so easily with $\phi$, and I've been trying to find an unbounded sequence for a long while . . .

Comment: Why is it a norm? $f'$ may not be defined for $f\in C([0,1])$ (the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$).

Comment: Does $C[0,1]$ mean (as it usually does) the continuous real valued functions on $[0,1]$? If so I think the space you're working with needs more differentiability assumptions, but I don't know the proper notation for indicating that.

Comment: @JohnZHANG It's $C^1$ sorry. I'll edit.

Comment: @coffeemath Indeed. I mean $C^1$ to be continuously differentiable functions.

Answer (score 1):

For Q1, by your argument, you have shown $f_n(0)\to a$ and $f_n'\to g\in C([0,1])$ in sup-norm. Then we define $f(t)=a_0+\int_0^t g(s)\,ds$ for $t\in [0,1]$. Then by fundamental theorem of calculus, it's clear that $f\in C^1([0,1])$ and $f'=g$. Then it follows that $f_n\to f$ in your norm.

Some thoughts about Q2. If we consider $f''(1)$ for simplicity, then the functional is not bounded since $f_n=\frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1}$ has norm $1$ but $f''_n(1)=n$. I think a similar counterexample can be constructed at the point $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Ah! I should've seen that the desired convergence came straight from the given norm . . . Thank you. Do you have any insight on the functional too? This one's really bugging me . . .

Comment: @user288742 Sorry I don't have an idea of the functional at this time. I think the restriction on polynomials gives a problem for constructing counterexamples.

Comment: take $g_n(x) = \sin(n x), x \in [0,1]$, it is a sequence of continuous and bounded functions, but $|g'_n(x)|$ is unbounded as $n \to \infty$. Then for each $g_n$ consider a polynomial $q_n$ such that $\sup_{x \in [0,1]} |g_n(x) - q_n(x)| < 1/n$. You'll get that $|q_n'(x)|$ is also unbounded, and your sequence of polynomials such that $\|p_n\|$ is bounded but $|p_n''(1/2)|$ diverges is $p_n(x) = \int_0^x q_n(t) dt$.  @user288742

Comment: I forgot to respond @user1952009. Thank you this is a valuable technique. I had one question - does $\| g_n - q_n\|_\infty \to 0 \implies \| g_n' -q_n'\| \to 0$? It seems intuitively correct but I don't know how to formally show this

Comment: @user288742  you ask if $\|g-f_n\|_\infty\to 0 \implies \|g'-f_n'\|_\infty\to 0$ ? no a counter-example is $g = 0, f_n = \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}$. Here I'm saying some sort of opposite : $g'(x)\ge A$ and $g(0) = 0$ and $\|g-q_n\|_\infty \to 0 \implies$  that $\sup_x q_n'(x) > A-\epsilon$ when $n \to \infty$

Comment: @user1952009 I see . . . thanks for the clarification & counterexample. How could I prove your correct statement?

Comment: @user288742   on $x \in [0,1/n]$ : $\|q_n(x)- \sin(nx)\|_\infty < 1/n \implies $ $q_n(1/n)-q_n(0) > 1-\frac{2}{n}$ thus by the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) $\sup_x q_n'(x) > n-2$  (and be careful, in my 1st comment I used $\|.\|$ for your norm, not the $\|.\|_\infty$ norm)

Comment: @user1952009 Excellent! Thanks again

Comment: @user1952009 Hey I have been thinking about your more general comment: "$g'(x) \ge A$ and $g(0)=0$ and $\|g-q_n\|_\infty \to 0 \implies $ that $\sup_x q_n'(x) > A-\epsilon$ when $n \to \infty$." I've been trying to prove this via MVT but I can't get anywhere. Can you help me out?